# Docker installation on Ubuntu 12.04 -> cannot connect to daemon

Tags: installation, docker, ubuntu-12.04

I tried to install docker on an ubuntu 12.04 system following the official documentation here
https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#for-precise-1204-lts (including the reboot) and here 
https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#installing-docker-on-ubuntu

Unfortunately this ended up with a `FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?`

```
$ docker version
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.1
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?

$ docker info
FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?

$ docker -d
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
FATA[0000] open /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/df72a4d378d4e5fc20dfba9c3356f94de84278a9864e838160ae2c1e3a6c4991: no such file or directory
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any similar case on the web and don't have advanced experience, so I would appreciate any help :)

**Solved** turns out I only had to delete the layers directory. :/